# Каким из этих тегов нужна закрывающая пара?

Tags: html5, валидация, tag, html-validation

[image: Тест на mail.ru]

Тест с сайта mail.ru, для получения сертификата HTML5.
Вопрос на картинке. Мой ответ был таким: script и time. Итог - ошибка. WTF?
Открываю htmlbook.ru. Смотрю...
Закрывающий тег...
html - Не обязателен, но хороший стиль...
br - Не требуется,
link - Не требуется,
script - Обязателен,
source - Не обязателен,
time - Обязателен.

Значение фразы "обязателен" и "не требуется" - понятно дураку, а вот "не обязателен" - уже можно интерпретировать по разному, видимо.

Ок, идем на https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML, и там про тег html:

> Открывающий тег может быть пропущен, если первое, что находится внутри элемента , не является комментарием.
>   В HTML5 закрывающий тег может быть пропущен."

Про тег source:

> "Должен иметь открывающий тег; закрывающий тег необязателен."

Comment: htmlbook вообще не истина в последней инстанции. Читайте учебники или хотя бы MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML

Comment: @YuriPokhylko, согласен. Я посмотрю, спасибо

Comment: Вопрос можно перефразировать так: у каких из тегов есть закрывающая пара?

Comment: @Leonid, такой вопрос был бы более корректен и не оставил бы вариантов. Наверное это и подразумевалось

Comment: Не исключено, что вопросы из эпохи ожидаемого повсеместного введения XHTML)) С точки зрения которого вопрос сформулирован корректно.

Comment: @Leonid, есть у меня подозрение, что закрывающий тег не нужен "empty elements", а для всех остальных нужен. Тег html - не пустой тег, уж точно, закрывающий тег у него есть и нужен, хоть в спецификации и написано "можно пропустить"

Answer (score 0):

Проходил тест повторно. Попался этот же вопрос. Поставил гвлочки напротив: href, script, time. Вуаля! Ошибки нет.